# Early 2020 dystopic YA survival film or series with a reality show premise

Tags: story-identification, dystopia

I remember seeing a trailer on IMDB in early 2020 for a film or series which I haven't heard from since.
Premise (my assumption): Teens are outdoors for a reality TV survival show when disaster strikes civilisation, turning the game — unbeknownst to them — into an actual struggle for their survival.

The trailer went like this:

- OPENING: A person's feet, dressed in white sneakers and jeans, walking across white sand overgrown with low shrubs. The person slips, slides down and gets heavily injured.
- ZOOMING OUT (from here on, the camera constantly zooms out at constant speed, giving us a series of reveals)
- REVEAL: The person is a caucasian male teen / young adult dressed in
  streetwear (black blazer). He calls for help.
- REVEAL: He's lying aside a dune. In a landscape that up to the horizon is only shrub-covered dunes with no other persons or infrastructure in sight. For this surroundings, his clothing seems unsuitable, ill-prepared.
- REVEAL: The same image, shown on a small screen.
- REVEAL: The screen is one of a set of several. Two further ones show other teenagers / young adults (one caucasian female, one Afro-American female) walking through similar landscape.
- REVEAL: Tech items set up around the monitors convey the impression that this is a TV studio recording for a show.
- REVEAL: A chair and the person sitting in it come into view. The person, a male, is dressed in typical camera crew attire (black tshirt, olive-grey cargo shorts).
- REVEAL: The person appears to be injured and isn't moving, despite the distress of the first male mentioned. It's not made clear but appears to be possible that this person, who could've sent help, is dead.
- Here, the camera turns sharply to the right.
- REVEAL: A TV standing next to a window, playing a news broadcast that reports of a bomb destroying a city. Making it doubtful that help would come from there.
- The camera continues to zoom out and we exit the...
- REVEAL: Airstream camper that contains the tech set up and crew person.
- REVEAL. It's parked in aforementioned dune landscape. And there is no one else around.

Please note:

- The details may be different (clothes, look of the characters) but the camera movement (combining a calm steady pace with a series of evermore shocking reveals) and landscape were very distinct and I'm certain I remember these correctly.
- Live action

Comment: Sounds a little like "[The Last One](https://www.kirkusreviews.com/book-reviews/alexandra-oliva/the-last-one/)", but it doesn't look like it's been turned into a film.